# No permission to retract/uninstall from CA, but from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, permissions, central-administration, solution-deployment

I have a weird permission-related problem. My account is entered as a local administrator, just to be on the safe side.

If I want to retract or remove solutions within the CA I am getting either an Access Denied (remove) error or an Exception stating that only machine administrators can create SPJobDefinitions (retract).

The exception message for retracting has the following wording:

> Access denied.  Only machine administrators are allowed to create
>   administration service job definitions of type:
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionDeploymentJobDefinition,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.

Unfortunatlely, there is nothing to be found in the logs for the above error, only for the Access Denied error when removing:

```
02/10/2015 11:02:38.14  w3wp.exe (0x10F0)   0x1F70  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    8u9s    Medium  Solution Deployment : Global solution mysolution.wsp, deployed to 0 servers. Deployment config object is null   48d45ec2-3ab6-4990-a6ae-4e59ae384ffd    
02/10/2015 11:02:38.14  w3wp.exe (0x10F0)   0x1F70  SharePoint Foundation   Runtime 6615    Critical    Access denied.  48d45ec2-3ab6-4990-a6ae-4e59ae384ffd
```

If I just fire up Powershell and use the two appropriate commands:

```
Uninstall-SPSolution -Identity mySolution.wsp -allwebapplications
Remove-SPSolution -identity mySolution.wsp -force
```

Everything works. How is this possible?

Comment: Have you opened Central Admin window (Internet Explorer) as Administrator ("Run as administrator")?

Comment: Yes Robert, sorry I forgot to mention this. I have tried it with IE and Chrome run explicitly as administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the reason for this was: but a simple reboot did the trick.